# Partial Differential Equations: D'Alembert Formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Solve the IVP:

$u_{tt}-c^{2}u_{xx}=0,$

$u(0,x)=e^{x},$

$u_{t}(0,x)=sin(x)$

with D'Alambert formula in the simplest explicit form.

Using the formula I obtained the following solution:

$u(x,t)=1/2[e^{x-ct}+e^{x+ct}]+1/(2c)[-cos(x+ct)+cos(x-ct)]$

Would really appreciate if anyone could confirm that I solved the problem correctly! thank you!!

Comment: Looks good to me... you can always be double sure if you just differentiate and see if it satisfies the equation given with the IC's.

Answer (score 1):

Applying  the d'Alembert's formula:
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=g(x)$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+t)+f(x-t)]+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}g(y)dy$$

If you pluck in the initial value, you get:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x+ct}+e^{x-ct})+\frac{1}{2c}(cos(x-ct)-cos(x+ct))$$